# <type= "input" runat = "server">

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know that we have client side controls and we have server side controls. Client side controls are basic HTML controls with  and all the other tags while server side controls are like `<asp:Button>` and `<asp: Textbox>`.

Now when I talk about something like  I know that this is going to be executed at the server so it is  a server control but it does not qualify for for an asp control at the same time.

How is it functionally different than  control?

Comment: All controls are client side controls! You have a lot more control over an `<asp:TextBox>` from the server side than an `<input runat="server">` but the client side rendering (and behaviour) is the same.

Comment: By adding runat="server" to a Html control allows it to be treated as a HtmlGenericControl which exposes mthods and properties you can access in your code behind files.

Comment: I wonder why people are voting to have this closed, by the way.

Comment: @MrLister Me too :( [And for "Not a real question"?]

Comment: @pst Bogus? No, far from it. It allows the html element to be controlled from the server side with its ID. Without `runat="server"` the server side can't see the element. (The attribute will also be removed from the resulting HTML in the browser.)

Comment: I think the question is about input vs Button when both are server controls.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, comments were helpful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you have something with `runat="server"` you give it an ID and you can manipulate it in your code as if it was a normal control (with specific properties that correspond with their normal HTML attributes)

Comment: when you say you can manipulate it as a normal control you mean as "other server side controls". is that correct? And going back to my question is it any different at all from <asp:Button> control?

Comment: the thing is, you don't know what <asp:button> will generate. It can be a `<input type=submit>` or it could be a `<button>`. You gain .NET specific functionality using <asp:button> but you lose exact control of how it will finally render.